# Iframe not being spawned yet same code with an alert works

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm trying to edit a page so that submitting the form instead just spawns an iframe. If I use this code:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var formItem = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[2];
  formItem.setAttribute('action', '');
  formItem.addEventListener('submit', createIframe, false);
}

function createIframe(){
  var ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME"); 
  ifrm.setAttribute("src", "http://127.0.0.1/myIframe.html"); 
  ifrm.style.width = "50%"; 
  ifrm.style.height = "50%"; 
  document.body.appendChild(ifrm); 
}
```

Then the iframe is not spawned when the form is submitted. If I, however, make the createIframe() function to:

```
function createIframe(){
    alert(1); 
    }
```

Then the alert is created when the form is submitted. Thus it must be an issue with my iframe code, but I can't figure out what! Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to cancel the `form`'s default behavior.

```
function createIframe(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //...
```

Without this, the form will submit the page to itself with an empty `action` attribute.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/eXuMg/1/)

[`event.preventDefault()` MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.preventDefault)

Comment: Worked perfectly - thanks so much! Was not familiar with preventDefault() so I have learnt something new as well - cheers!

Comment: @Jingo No problem. `=]` In that case, I just linked to the `preventDefault()` MDN page in my answer which shows another example, even though the name is quite self-explanatory. `:)`